# How do I set the ngModel for dynamically added new input rows angular 4+ (mat-table)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I will keep it short , i want to add ngModel to dynamically added new input rows (I have Mat table with multiple rows with add element method which adds new row everytime on click of button) so that i can bind the user entered values and send to Backend,

Please see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-5fmwbp?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: The example that you have shared its jus working fine - you can get the all values by using - `myformArray?.value`

Comment: Do you need something else to be happen?

Comment: Ya the same way, myformArray?.value gives me all the values , what if i want only name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the array of all values you can use:

```
this.myformArray.value
```

To get the array of particular key like name then you can use map operator:

```
this.myformArray.value.map(x => x.name); // will return ["n1","n2","n3"]
```